# If $XYZ=ZXY$ does $e^Xe^Ye^Z=e^Ze^Xe^Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is well known that if $X,Y$ are commuting matrices, then their exponential commute:
$$XY=YX\quad\implies\quad e^Xe^Y=e^Ye^X.$$
Now, I am wondering if the following generalization holds:

> **Question:** If $XYZ=ZXY$, does $e^Xe^Ye^Z=e^Ze^Xe^Y$?

Note that if $Z$ commutes with both $X$ and $Y$, then it is obvious.

Comment: I do not believe that. $XYZ=ZXY$ does not imply $X^2 Y^2 Z^2 = Z^2 X^2 Y^2$, for instance, so the two Cauchy products $$\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{X^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{Y^n}{n!}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{Z^n}{n!}\right)$$ and $$\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{Z^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{X^n}{n!}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{Y^n}{n!}\right)$$ may not match.

Comment: Hint: What if $Y=0$?

Comment: It's fine to speculate like this, but even better is to examine the _proof_ that commuting matrices have commuting exponentials ("the binomial theorem applies"), then to ask yourself if there's any reason to expect the _proof_ generalizes. Here the answer is a clear "no", as Jack D'Aurizio notes. And user1551's comment, perhaps the first or second case one "ought" to try, immediately dispatches the conjecture. :)

Answer (score 12):

OP is asking if

> $$ [XY,Z]~=~0\qquad  \stackrel{?}{\Rightarrow}\qquad [e^Xe^Y,e^Z]~=~0~? \tag{1}$$

In a comment above, user1551 has already pointed out obvious counterexamples if $X=0$ xor $Y=0$.

Here we will give a counterexample with invertible $2\times 2$ matrices, namely the [Pauli matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices):

$$ X~=~ i\pi \sigma_x, \qquad  Y~=~ \frac{i\pi}{2} \sigma_y, \qquad Z~=~ \frac{i\pi}{2} \sigma_z, \tag{2}$$

$$ e^X~=~ -{\bf 1}_{2\times 2}, \qquad  e^Y~=~  i\sigma_y, \qquad e^Z~=~ i\sigma_z. \tag{3}$$

Now $XY$ is proportional to $\sigma_z$ and therefore commutes with $Z$; while $e^Xe^Y$ is proportional to $\sigma_y$, and hence anticommutes with $e^Z$ (rather than commutes).

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ commute, $$e^Y e^X = e^X e^Y = e^{X+Y}$$
So $Z$ needs to commute with $X+Y$ for that to be true in this particular case, and not with $e^{XY}$.

An easy counterexample is $Y=0$, $X$ and $Z$ such that $[X,Z]\neq 0$. The condition is still fulfilled but, obviously, $e^X e^Z \neq e^Z e^X$ in the general case.

Comment: $e^Z$ and $e^{X+Y}$ commute does not imply that $Z,X+Y$ commute. In the same way $[X,Z]\not= 0$ does not imply that $e^Xe^Z\not= e^Ze^X$.

Comment: And that's why I said "in the general case"

Comment: For point 1. You write "So $Z$ needs..." that is false. For point 2. "in the general case" implies that "it is true for any matrices". That you must write is: "for generic matrices, one has....". Moreover, this last result is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If $(XY)Z=Z(XY)$ we can only say that 
$$
e^Ze^{XY}=e^{XY}e^Z=e^{Z+XY}
$$